# Call function result missing 'value' while automating a certain page using Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate a certain page. I want to make the mouse click anywhere in the page, but I am getting the following error:

```
call function result missing 'value'
```

The elements in the page is:

```
<div id="b1" iframegroupid="P1" class="btn_act"><img src="theme/images/hi.png" draggable="false"><span>K</span></div>
```

Another element is:

```
<div draggable="false" role="presentation" tabindex="0" class="xc" widgetid="SCREEN_field_Submit" id="CLOSE_1" title="">
```

The code that I have is:

```
WebElement close_frame = Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("P1"));
    //driver.get(Constant.geturl());
    driver.switchTo().frame(close_frame);
WebElement btn1 = Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("CLOSE_1"));
    btn1 .click();
```

I dont understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you using chrome driver? if so, what is ur chrome driver version and chrome browser version? May be chrome driver and chrome browser mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have to update your chromedriver with latest verion.
update to update chromedriver to 2.36 or greter, older versions have such issues.

i am also confused about your Driver.driver.   and directly driver.  methods.
try using

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("P1")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<CLOSE_1>));
driver.findElement(By.id("CLOSE_1")).click();
```